# crontab Failed to import the site module

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I want crontab to run the python script for a public welfare project.

I can successfully run the script in Pycharm.

When I run it with crontab, there is an error.

> Environment: Mac OS, python3.5

After I type 'crontab -e', it shows that:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/python3:/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/


32 14 * * * PATH=$PATH:/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/ cd /Users/yy/PycharmProjects/selenium_test/ &&  /Users/yy/anaconda/bin/python3 /Users/yy/PycharmProjects/selenium_test/selenium_test.py >> /Users/yy/PycharmProjects/selenium_test/log.txt
```

I got an error as follows in the /var/mail/username:

```
From yy@YY.local  Thu Jun  8 14:32:00 2017
Return-Path: <yy@YY.local>
X-Original-To: yy
Delivered-To: yy@YY.local
Received: by YY.local (Postfix, from userid 501)
    id A7F1F38FFFCC; Thu,  8 Jun 2017 14:32:00 -0500 (CDT)
From: yy@YY.local (Cron Daemon)
To: yy@YY.local
Subject: Cron <yy@YY> PATH=$PATH:/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/ cd /Users/yy/PycharmProjects/selenium_test/ &&  /Users/yy/anaconda/bin/python3 /Users/yy/PycharmProjects/selenium_test/selenium_test.py >> /Users/yy/PycharmProjects/selenium_test/log.txt
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/python3:/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=yy>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=yy>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/yy>
Message-Id: <20170608193200.A7F1F38FFFCC@YY.local>
Date: Thu,  8 Jun 2017 14:32:00 -0500 (CDT)

Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 567, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/yy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 550, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/Users/yy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 327, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/Users/yy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 206, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/Users/yy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 162, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "/Users/yy/anaconda/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 127: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I spent two hours on this error.
However, No solutions work... 
Please help.
Thanks!

#

> I use python3.5, so the default encoding is utf-8. The
>   UnicodeDecodeError is strange...

Comment: Strange things I am noticing: 1) an executable on your PATH: `/Users/yy/anaconda/bin/python3`; 2) the anaconda install comes after `/usr/bin` on your PATH, making it pretty much useless

Comment: I want to clarify sth. I am a phd candidate at UIC, and I work on a public welfare project (collect and spread missing people information without payment for more than a year). The problem: The script runs well in pycharm, but got an error with contrab. It's reasonable to believe that there is a bug with contrab. I debug for a few hours, and finally find that it's the encoding problem. Yes, maybe the question doesn't match the answer very well. However, it's the procedure that how I analyze and solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is about encoding.
The default of Python3.5 is utf-8.

However, some packages I installed is encoded with Unicode.

I solve the problem by modifying the site.py file in path=/Users/user_name/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site.py.

Line 158:

> ```
>     f = open(fullname, "rb") ->  f = open(fullname, "rb")
> ```

Line 163:

> ```
>     if line.startswith("#"): ->  if line.startswith(b"#"):
> ```

Line 166:

> if line.startswith(("import ", "import\t")): -> if line.startswith((b"import ", b"import\t")):

Line 170:

> dir, dircase = makepath(sitedir, line) -> dir, dircase = makepath(sitedir, str(line))

I don't think it's a good idea to modify the "site.py" in anaconda...

But this fix the problem.
Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you just save the files with ascii encoding and use unicode escapes for the weird stuff?

Comment: Your answer also highlights how little information your question actually provides, making it less likely that the question will be particularly useful to someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The site.py actually read the files in site-packages, which are managed by Anaconda....The default encoding of python3.5 is utf8. Hence, the files in site-packages are encoded with utf8.  I think the problem is probably that I installed some packages that encoding=unicode recently, which casue the problem...

Comment: I think you are right. We can find the files that encoding=unicode, and save it as utf8....In this case, we don't have to modify the site.py

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. At the beginning, I mistakenly believe that it's the crontab's bug... Becasue I can successfully run the script in pycharm...